# How to show following converges to $1$ uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, uniform-convergence

Define $U_N=\left(\ \dfrac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi } \right)\ \left(\ z^{-1}+\sum_{n=-N}^{n=N}(-1 )^n \left(\ (z-n)^{-1}+n^{-1}   \right)\ \right)$ .
where sum runs when $n$ is not equal to $0$.
I want to show that $U_N$ converges to 1 uniformly as $N$ tend to $\infty$.I tried by expanding $\sin(\pi z)$ but not able to get anything.Please help in solving this or give any suggestion or any reference.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The full definition of $U_N$ should probably mention that $(-1)^n\frac {\sin \pi z}{\pi (z-n)}$ is assigned the value $1$ at $z=n$, which also makes it clearer that $U_N-U_{N-1}$ is close to $1 $ at $z=N$. Proving uniform convergence on an arbitrarily large disc around $0$ might be feasible.